# Bubble Sort Visualization (Repaint Error)

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, user-interface

```
Thread one = new Thread(){
    public void run(){
        while(true){
            for (int m=listlen-1;m>=1;m--){
                flag=0;

                for (int n=0;n<m;n++){
                    if (a[n+1]<a[n]){
                        temp=a[n+1];
                        repaint();
                        a[n+1]=a[n];
                        repaint();
                        a[n]=temp;
                        repaint();
                        flag=1;
                    }
                }

                if (flag==0){
                    m=0;
                }
            }
            try 
            {
                Thread.sleep (100); 

            } 
            catch (InterruptedException ex) 
            {
            }
        }
    }
};
one.start();
```

Hello friends of Stack Overflow, I've stumbled across a problem in my code which I'm having a degree of difficulty of trying to wrap my head around.
 I'm creating a GUI that displays the objects as they're being sorted by this Bubble Sort. However what my code currently accomplishes is show the finished list and then it displays it, 
I believe this is a problem with my thread but I haven't been able to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing the waiting (`Thread.sleep(100)`) outside of of your outer `for` loop, and hence *after* the sorting is finished.

Instead, you should put the waiting *inside* the body of your `for` loop, or may be even before each of your `repaint()` calls.

```
Thread one = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            for (int m = listlen - 1; m >= 1; m--) {
                flag = 0;
                    for (int n = 0; n < m; n++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(100);
                    } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                    }
                    if (a[n + 1] < a[n]) {
                        temp = a[n + 1];
                        repaint();
                        a[n + 1] = a[n];
                        repaint();
                        a[n] = temp;
                        repaint();
                        flag = 1;
                    }
                }

                if (flag == 0) {
                    m = 0;
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
one.start();
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked perfectly, I didn't know you could add a thread.sleep inside a loop.